# Paging caml query results

Tags: caml-query

I have about 1000 items in a custom list. i want to retrieve 10 only from a certain position, (i know how to do this).

I also want to get the total in the list.

How would i do this? (this is for custom paging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried getting the list and using [`SPList.Items.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.items.aspx)?

There is also an [`SPList.ItemCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.itemcount.aspx) property that includes folders as items in the count...

Comment: This needs to be selected before the query limits the list. Afterwards it acts as an amount with the RowLimit as the maximum amount.

Comment: @HughWood is this additional information or are you saying this isn't a valid answer?

Comment: Not at all, I am saying that I am putting a caveat on Item Count. If it wasn't valid I would of down voted.

Comment: @HughWood definitely. I was just unsure where you were going with that.